# What is the general age of users on Physics SE?

Tags: discussion, users

I want to what is the age of users in general. I want to ask this because age determines so many things. A student of age 30 can be far better than a student of age 17. I know it’s personal information which you will not want to share but I just want a rough idea.

Comment: You can't know for sure, and it's difficult to collect the statistics without an actual survey. The age of users used to be publicly visible in the past (provided they correctly filled in their birthdate), but isn't anymore. C.f. [Where did the age go on the network profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294637/where-did-the-age-go-on-the-network-profile)

Comment: The StackExchange model is built on merit, not age.

Comment: @JonCuster so can an infant ever be Physics researcher?

Comment: If they answer questions properly on Physics SE, yes. And, having once been an infant, I can attest that they can become physicists...

Comment: @JonCuster I hope your dream will come true one day.

Comment: What dream? All physicists were infants at one point.

Comment: @JonCuster But no infants are physicists.

Comment: @JonCuster Age does matter some percent

Comment: You have to be at least older than 13 (or 16 in Europe) to create an account on SE though, so let's just drop the hypothetical example of an infant... but anyway, someone of age 60 who doesn't use Physics in daily work/life can be far worse than a genius of age 13 who loves Physics, so the age doesn't really tell anything...

Comment: @Andrew T Were you more wisdom full in your UG years or are you now more wisdom full?

Comment: On a side note: I understand there are only 3 fields of human endeavour where one can find child prodigies: music, chess, and mathematics.  At any rate this would exclude physics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is not systematically collected anywhere, so the best that you can expect is a general impression.

There are a few users in our chat room who occasionally reveal their age, directly or indirectly: high schooler students or college undergraduates preparing for entrance exams for college or graduate school, and a couple who are partly or completely retired. But that's not a representative sample of the userbase for the site as a whole. Most of our community doesn't participate in chat.

I personally don't think that age is very important, so I spent some years aging non-monotonically. For example, I turned thirty-seven in 2013 and 2016,
and thirty-nine in 2015, 2017, and 2018. (I think.)
My children are of an age where birthdays and ages are a Big Deal, and they find this *infuriating*.

Comment: I'm quite sure that people setting up SE accounts through Google need to check a box saying that they allow Google to share personal information with SE (not sure though, since that's not the route I took to create my account). Google accounts require birthdays as mandatory information (though it isn't verified). Can the powers that be (mods and/or community team members) see this information for that particular set of users?

Comment: @Chair No, mods and community managers can't see that information. Can't speak for the SE developers (who have access to the codebase) but I think that given the new GDPR restrictions they wouldn't go out of their way to look for that data.

Comment: @Chair there's a quite recent meta post on MSE (regarding invalid Google privacy leak) that SE only gets and uses email, full name, and display picture once for registration purpose. Others than those (e.g. birthday) are simply ignored.

Comment: Oooohhh, that sounds like a neat trick. What do I need to do to turn 25 in 2019?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Well, how old are are you planning to turn in 2019?